# Using relative imports in python with mutliple parent and children folders

Tags: python, import, sys

I had a small problem with importing a script that was in a parent folder, but I managed to resolve it using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

My directory is like this:

```
Data
|->->code
     |->->script1.py
     |->->->->subfolder
              |->->->script2.py
```

When I run script2 (which imports script1) from the subfolder directory, the script runs without problems. But if I try to run script2 from the code directory using:

```
:~ ./subfolder/script2.py
```

I get an error :

```
ImportError: No module named script1
```

I tried using relative imports but because my code is not structured in packages it doesn't work. Is there a way I can run script2 from both directories (the parent and the child) and still be able to import script1 everytime?

Thank you in advance,
Georgi Nikolov

**EDIT**: Ok, after I read through all the suggestions, I did a "simple" hack which is quite ugly in my opinion but works quite well:

```
import sys
parent_folder = sys.path[0].split("/subfolder")[0]
sys.path.append(parent_folder)
import script1
```

Now I can even call script2 from the root and it will manage to import script1

Comment: python version? 2.7 and 3.x has different default behavior of importing (which confuses me a lot). but generally speaking, if you want to reuse the code, it's better to make it a package. it eases your life, and the others want to reference to your work.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I am using 2.7 and I can't package the code because it will mean starting all over which is unfeasable. Is there a way still to do this without having to switch to packages?

Comment: you just need to handle the `pwd` or `cwd` problem. you just append `../` to the path of the file.

Answer (score 1):

To import a module that is up a level, you can use this.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
```

**An Explanation**

```
__file__            # The full path to your running file.
os.path.dirname     # See below. (1)
os.path.join        # See below. (2)
sys.path.append     # See below. (3)
".."                # Universal for "up a level".
```

1. `os.path.dirname(path)` -

   > [Return the directory name of pathname path.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)
2. `os.path.join(path, *paths)` -

   > [Join one or more path components intelligently.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
3. `sys.path` -

   > [A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

You can add a string with the `append` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use absolute paths:

```
import sys, os
HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(HERE, ".."))
```

But better do not do this: [Guido views running scripts within a package as an anti-pattern](http://blindvic.blogspot.com/2012/04/guido-views-running-scripts-within.html)

You should put the standalone scripts in the root folder of the project. A script should not be used as a module and as the main script.

If you cannot move the script to the root, make another bootstrap script at the root which will import your service script running a dedicated function in it.